# why javax is not runnig in this project while is runnig in others

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-boot-starter

Jakrta is runnig in this project but when i turned in javax it dont work. By working with jakarta the creation of D.B didn't work.

[image: jakrta is runnig in this project but when i turned in javax it dont work]

Comment: 1. Please don't post images of code.  Please copy and paste the code into the question.  2. `javax.persistence` looks like a JEE class, so I think you need to make sure you have those libraries included in the project.  Do you?

Comment: how can i make sure of that

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Most likely a missing dependency on your pom.xml